# Which ML Model should I choose for text classififcation and how do I validate it?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, model

I have been given a large dataset of names. I have split them into words and classified them in the form of True/False values for Junk, FirstName, LastName, and Entity. i.e.

| Name | Junk | FirstName | LastName | Entity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| Doe | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| School | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Which model should I use to train this model? How do I perform validation such that I can give custom inputs in the form of strings and get an output. Also how do I do thresholding?

I have tried Naive Bayes, KNN and Logistic Regression. How do I do thresholding and validation for inputs?

Comment: This question is better suited for [datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Please have a look at the guide for [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) questions.